# How to add a method to ActiveStorage::Variant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, overriding, monkeypatching, rails-activestorage

I want to add a method to `ActiveStorage::Variant` How to do it?

I have this for ActiveStorage::Blob and it works when I modify code without reloading the server :

`config/initializers/active_storage_direct_url.rb` :

```
module ActiveStorageDirectUrl
  def cloudfront_url(expires_at = nil)
    # xx
  end
end

ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_storage_blob) do
  ActiveStorage::Blob.include ActiveStorageBlobCachedUrl
end
```

But the issue is when I do it for ActiveStorage::Variant. I tried this :

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_storage_blob) do
  ActiveStorage::Variant.include ActiveStorageVariantCachedUrl
end
```

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_storage_variant) do
  ActiveStorage::Variant.include ActiveStorageVariantCachedUrl
end
```

But it in both case, in dev environment, when I modify some code and without restarting the server, it says `undefined method 'direct_url' for #<ActiveStorage::Variant:0x00007fc04fa45530>`

When I reload the `rails server` it works though. Same thing for sidekiq, I need to reload it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :

```
ActiveSupport::Reloader.to_prepare do
  ActiveStorage::Variant.include ActiveStorageVariantCachedUrl
end
```